# The column id must be mapped to a field

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Just changed some setting to a doctrine entity configuration and got the following execption

```
The column id must be mapped to a field in class VSmart\OrmBundle\Entity\Ob
ject since it is referenced by a join column of another class.
```

I would expect that the column `id` is not mapped to a field in `Object`. Though, see here the code of that particular mapping:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

So, what is the exception really trying to tell me?

**Update**

This is the other end of the relation.

Object definition:

```
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Address", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \Entis
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entis",inversedBy="objects")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="EntisId", referencedColumnName="Id")
     * })
     */
    private $entis;

    /**
     * @var \Objecttype
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ObjectType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ObjectType", referencedColumnName="Id")
     * })
     */
    private $objectType;

    /**
     * @var \Unit
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Unit")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="UnitId", referencedColumnName="Id")
     * })
     */
    private $unit;

    /**
     * @var \Dimension
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dimension")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="DimensionId", referencedColumnName="Id")
     * })
     */
    private $dimension;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag") */
    private $tags;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Measurement", mappedBy="object")
     */
    private $measurements;
```

Comment: Probably that the column name should be id and not Id

Comment: @Cerad the column name is `Id` in MySQL

Comment: Yep.  And if you look in the class that's trying to join it you probably just used the defaults.  So it's trying to join against id and not Id.  If not then ignore these comments.

Comment: @Cerad I added the definition of the fields of Object

Comment: @Cerad do you whether I can output which Entity references the entity Object and gives throws the exception?

Comment: php app\console doctrine:schema:validate :-)